# how to redirect to the public folder

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

**When filling on hosting, I faced the problem that you can not select the start folder of the opening. When opening a link юhttps://my-domen/ this opens**

[image]

to get to the site, enter /public 
how to make sure that when you open the site, the public folder is immediately opened on the hosting so you can not configure it . Can I use htaccess or something else? If this helps then the laravel files are a clean project

**htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your root folder use this `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In the public folder use the new clean laravel `.htaccess` file

Comment: do I need to clear the file and put these lines there, or add them?

Comment: Where you get that .htaccess? It seems from joomla or something

Comment: In the public folder in the laravel project

Comment: Leave that file in the public folder. Don't change it. Put the htaccess of this answer in the root directory of your domain.

Comment: I don't understand you

Comment: When you connect with ftp to your hosting, you are in the root directory, and you can see there is "public" folder, right? Put the .htaccess of this answer in the root directory of your hosting.

Comment: thank you very much I suffered for a couple of days